# Is there any method to have voice input in Duckduckgo browser on Android?

Tags: voice-recognition, incognito-mode, duckduckgo

Duckduckgo browser (Andriod) works well. It uses only the incognito mode, for enforcing privacy and security. The Gboard keyboard disables voice input on incognito mode.

Is there any way to get voice input while using Duckduckgo? Use another keyboard? Gboard voice input can be enabled?

Comment: It says it has a private voice search function, but that just beeps. Anyways it's a deal breaker for me. So adios duck duck go.